# Pegar o ultimo ID ao inserir no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Como pegar o ultimo ID ao inserir no BD MySQL, usando PHP e MYSQLi.

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome) VALUE (
          'Fulano',
          'De tall'
");

echo $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
```

> Esta retornando 0.

Comment: Me parece que faltou um **`)`** no seu `insert` na declação `value`. Veja se o `insert` esta funcionando.

Comment: @gato Verdade. Coloquei o `)` e funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Pior que essa falta não acusa erro.

Answer (score 2):

O problema já foi solucionado, mas eu acrescentaria uma dica util. Você pode fazer com que os erros nas consultas sql sejam mostrados como exceptions do php, permitindo um debug mais rapido. Isso pode ser feito com o uso da função mysqli_report. Exemplo:

```
$driver_mysqli = new mysqli_driver();
$driver_mysqli->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;

$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome) VALUE (
          'Fulano',
          'De tall'
");

echo $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
```